# shell variable test expansion problem

Tags: shell, sed, quoting, variable

I have this code:

```
sed \
$( (( $compress == 1 )) && echo -n '-e /^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/' ) \
-e "s|\*\*jobname\*\*|$jobname|g" \
-e "s|\*\*hostname\*\*|$hostname|g" \
-e "s|\*\*hostport\*\*|$hostport|g" \
-e "s|\*\*rmttrailname\*\*|$rmttrailname|g" < $GGPARAMSDIR/pump.template > 
$GGPARAMSDIR/$jobname.prm
```

that almost works like I want.  If `$compress == 1`, I want the `sed` to include the string `-e /^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/'`.  And if `$compress != 1`, don't include that section.

I'm getting the following error when `$compress is 1`

```
 sed: -e expression #1, char 10: missing command
```

When I add a set -x to the script for debugging it expands to the following:

```
sed -e '/^RMTHOST/' 's/$/,' compress/ -e 's|\*\*jobname\*\*|pssic|g' -e 's|\*\*hostname\*\*|omsssi|g' -e 's|\*\*hostport\*\*|7809|g' -e 's|\*\*rmttrailname\*\*|./dirdat/dsn/rc|g'
```

Notice the single ticks closing the first `-e` expression after the `/^RMTHOST/`, which I'm sure is the cause of my problem.  But I can't figure out the syntax to fix it.

FYI, the values of the variables are `jobname=pssic`, `hostname=omsssi`, and `hostport=7809`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Same effect.  the problem is not actually the test, its what is echo'ed after the true condition of the test.

Comment: Its some combination of altering the quotes, but that isn't it.

Comment: the '/' are part of the sed substitution.

Comment: If I change the line to:
$( (( $compress == 1 )) && echo -n "-e '/^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/'" ) \

The result in set -x is:
sed -e ''\''/^RMTHOST/' 's/$/,' 'compress/'\''' -e 's|\*\*jobname\*\*|pssic|g' -e 's|\*\*hostname\*\*|omsssi|g' -e 's|\*\*hostport\*\*|7809|g' -e 's|\*\*rmttrailname\*\*|./dirdat/dsn/rc|g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

The problem is that the result of a command substitution is subjected to both pathname expansion and word splitting.

To see what happens to the output of the command substitution, let's use `printf` to display the words that it produces:

```
$ printf ">%s<\n" $( (( compress == 1 )) && echo -n '-e /^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/' )
>-e<
>/^RMTHOST/<
>s/$/,<
>compress/<
```

You do need `-e` to be a separate word.  Observe, however, the word-splitting also caused the sed substitute command to be broken up into something that sed will *not* understand:

```
$ sed -e '/^RMTHOST/' 's/$/,' 'compress/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: missing command
```

#### The solution

Try using bash arrays instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
jobname=pssic
hostname=omsssi
hostport=7809
compress=1
rmttrailname=SomethingElse

args=()
(( compress == 1 )) && args+=('-e' '/^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/')
args+=(
    -e "s|\*\*jobname\*\*|$jobname|g"
    -e "s|\*\*hostname\*\*|$hostname|g"
    -e "s|\*\*hostport\*\*|$hostport|g"
    -e "s|\*\*rmttrailname\*\*|$rmttrailname|g"
    )

declare -p args  # Optional: Verify the args are what we want.

sed "${args[@]}" <"$GGPARAMSDIR/pump.template" >"$GGPARAMSDIR/$jobname.prm"
```

#### Good reading

An interesting and more general discussion of the problems of creating commands out of shell variables is: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: You nailed it.  It works perfect.

Many thanks.
BF

Comment: As the tag is shell (not bash, ksh or zsh), a POSIX solution should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

#### A POSIX solution:

**Unquoted** command substitutions are subject to word splitting.

Change:

```
$( (( $compress == 1 )) && echo -n '-e /^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/' ) \
```

To (quote the expansion):

```
-e "$( [ "$compress" -eq 1 ] && printf '%s' '/^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/' )" \
```

That sets two arguments, one is `-e` and the other is the string sed needs.

Edited script:

```
#!/bin/sh

compress=$1
jobname=pssic
hostname=omsssi
hostport=7809
rmttrailname=ends
#set -x
echo "RMTHOST **jobname** **hostname** **hostport** **rmttrailname** test" | \
    sed \
    -e "$( [ "$compress" -eq 1 ] && printf '%s' '/^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/' )" \
    -e "s|\*\*jobname\*\*|$jobname|g" \
    -e "s|\*\*hostname\*\*|$hostname|g" \
    -e "s|\*\*hostport\*\*|$hostport|g" \
    -e "s|\*\*rmttrailname\*\*|$rmttrailname|g"
#set +x
```

And testing the code (without `set -x`):

```
$  ./so 1
RMTHOST pssic omsssi 7809 ends test, compress
```

If the set -x is uncommented:

```
$ ./so 1
+ echo RMTHOST **jobname** **hostname** **hostport** **rmttrailname** test
+ [ 1 -eq 1 ]
+ printf %s /^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/
+ sed -e /^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/ -e s|\*\*jobname\*\*|pssic|g -e s|\*\*hostname\*\*|omsssi|g -e s|\*\*hostport\*\*|7809|g -e s|\*\*rmttrailname\*\*|ends|g
RMTHOST pssic omsssi 7809 ends test, compress
+ set +x
```

#### Shells that use arrays

One completely different approach (and the best practice) is to accumulate all arguments as an array (only shells that have arrays):

```
#!/bin/bash
compress=$1
jobname=pssic
hostname=omsssi
hostport=7809
rmttrailname=ends

args=()
(( compress == 1 )) && args+=('-e' '/^RMTHOST/ s/$/, compress/')
args+=( -e "s|\*\*jobname\*\*|$jobname|g" )
args+=( -e "s|\*\*hostname\*\*|$hostname|g" )
args+=( -e "s|\*\*hostport\*\*|$hostport|g" )
args+=( -e "s|\*\*rmttrailname\*\*|$rmttrailname|g" )

echo "RMTHOST **jobname** **hostname** **hostport** **rmttrailname** test" | \
    sed "${args[@]}"
```

Running:

```
$ ./script 1
RMTHOST pssic omsssi 7809 ends test, compress
```